# Zipping two list of lists

Tags: python

Need help that I got lost in zipping two lists of lists (matrix).

The matrices that exactly the same format, that I would like them to be zipped in tuple pairs for each element in the same position.

For example,

```
m1 = [['A', 'B', 'C'],
      ['D', 'E'],
      ['F', 'G']]

m2 = [['s1', 's2', 's3'],
      ['s4', 's5'],
      ['s1', 's3']]
```

What I expect to get is, with the same format:

```
z = [[('A', 's1'), ('B', 's2'), ('C', 's3')],
     [('D', 's4'), ('E', 's5')],
     [('F', 's1'), ('G', 's3')]]
```

I can write a function to do this but I am looking for an elegant way of doing this in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zip()` and `zip()` again:

```
[zip(*paired) for paired in zip(m1, m2)]
```

The [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) pairs up each element of the input sequences; `m1[0]` with `m2[0]`, `m1[1]` with `m2[1]`, etc., and then for each of those pairs you then pair the elements again (`m1[0][0]` with `m2[0][0]`, `m1[0][1]` with `m2[0][1]`, etc.).

If this is Python 3, you'll have to wrap one of those in a `list()` call:

```
[list(zip(*paired)) for paired in zip(m1, m2)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> m1 = [['A', 'B', 'C'],
...       ['D', 'E'],
...       ['F', 'G']]
>>> m2 = [['s1', 's2', 's3'],
...       ['s4', 's5'],
...       ['s1', 's3']]
>>> [zip(*paired) for paired in zip(m1, m2)]
[[('A', 's1'), ('B', 's2'), ('C', 's3')], [('D', 's4'), ('E', 's5')], [('F', 's1'), ('G', 's3')]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I expected.