# Adding items from one list to another list of lists

Tags: python, list, iterable, unpack, iterable-unpacking

Suppose I have the following lists:

```py
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
list_2 = [11,12,13,14]
```

How can I add items from the second list to each of the items from the first one?

Stated clearly, this is the result I'm looking for:

```py
desired_output = [[1, 2, 11], [3, 4, 12], [5, 6, 13], [7, 8, 14]]
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried using the `zip` function, but the results I get are nested:

```py
list(zip(list_1,list_2))
# [((1, 2), 11), ((3, 4), 12), ((5, 6), 13), ((7, 8), 14)]
```

Notice how it doesn't follow the actual desired output because of the extra degree of nesting.

Comment: You have a good start. Now iterate over the result of `zip()` to combine each tuple into a single list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!! I actually was able to solve the problem while writing this question. In the end, I just posted my own answer below simultaneously with the original question.

Comment: lol, I didn't even look at the author of the answer. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
zip(*zip(*list_1), list_2)
```

Explained: there is a canonical way to transpose a list, `zip(*lst)`. All we're doing here is transposing, zipping, and transposing again

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This is even quicker than the list comprehension version!!! Btw, I think you've got an extraneous closing parehtesis at the end. Or a missing `list(` at the beginning =)

Comment: Using the `%timeit` magic command, this solution seems to take about 756ns on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension combined with a `zip`:

```py
desired_output = [[*x, y] for x,y in zip(list_1,list_2)]

print(desired_output)
# [[1, 2, 11], [3, 4, 12], [5, 6, 13], [7, 8, 14]]
```

Note that `*x` unpacks the items of `list_1`, `y` just takes each individual item from `list_2` and `[*x, y]` packs them back into one single list. Finally, the list comprehension around all of that takes care of iterating over everything and generating the full list.

PS: I'm answering my own question because I was able to figure out the solution on my own while writing the original question. I found hints to the solution in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31781072/8667016). But since that other post deals with a slightly different problem, I thought it would be beneficial to write a separate post here dedicated to this specific problem.

Comment: It's simpler if you unpack the tuple: `[[*x, y] for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2)]`

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks for the idea! I'm gonna edit the answer and do that.

Comment: Using the `%timeit` magic command, this solution seems to take about 797ns on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a list and a value for each pairing produced by zip.  this requires converting the individual value to a small list (or some other means of creating a merged list):

```
[s1+[i2] for s1,i2 in zip(list_1,list_2)]
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! I think this is the quickest out of all the answers so far. One small wrinkle though: it's not generalizable to cases where we're working with `tuples` and `tuples of tuples` (instead of `lists` and `lists` of `lists` as stated in the prompt). This wasn't mentioned anywhere in the original question, so it's impossible for you to have known I was looking for that too. Anyways, thanks for the lightning-fast answer!

Comment: Using the `%timeit` magic command, this solution seems to take about 723ns on my PC.

Answer (score -1):

I might be missing something but can't you just use a .append function?

```
list_1[0].append(list_2[0])
```

Comment: Hi @computer_goblin! Thanks for the answer!!! No, you're not missing anything - you're right, we can definitely use the `append` function. But the solution you provided only appends stuff to the first item. I'm looking for a solution that does that to all the items in the two lists and doesn't need to rely on a `for` loop.

Comment: Understandable have a great day